# How to make the scrolling faster in UITableView when the table has thousands of rows?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

My app has a UITableView and the table has near 5 Thousand rows (the app basically displays history in the form of vertical timeline), it's very tedious to scroll from top to bottom or vice versa, Any suggestions how can i make the scrolling better (faster), i don't wanna inculde section indexes to the right of the screen. Regards.

Comment: move you finger on the screen faster:d

Comment: It may take time to load thousands of rows as while scrolling every cell is created I would suggest to use the custom cell and load 50 or 100  rows first if user wanna scroll down then load another 50 or 100 !!

Comment: Rethink your design, scrolling 5000 rows with your finger is, as you say, tedious, especially if you won't use an index.

Comment: make cell height smaller as possible, expand if needed

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented a search field? This could be used by users to find a specific entry, or range of entries. Then, when they scroll, they are only looking at a filtered list.

Also, try and categorise the rows, to create more of a hierarchical navigation, and reduce the number of rows per screen.

Comment: I can't change the structure of the program since it is the desgin requirement of the application. Any better idea how can i improve the user experience + performance?

Comment: Talk to your client about this issue, and explain the "design requirements" might need to change.

Answer (score -1):

One of the way to make scrolling efficient is 'reusing' UITableViewCell

Comment: The question is about improving the user interface to make scrolling faster, not in terms of performance or optimisation of code.

Comment: My answer is for the line from Question "Any suggestions how can i make the scrolling better (faster)"
U got me